# Transfer BTC to EUR to someone else's bank account

Tags: money-transfer

I have BTC and someone else has a bank account (in Euro).
Are there options for me to transfer an amount from my BTC wallet to their EUR bank account?

Answer (score -1):

You can check out **Cashila** - https://www.cashila.com/

It's a EU-licensed payment processor that enables you to send your bitcoins to a third-party bank account. Great for paying your bills or sending someone some fiat.

It works the other way around too. You can receive payments/deposits from whoever you want into your online wallet, both SEPA and bitcoin.